# How to determine the SE and 95% confidence interval of a prediction using standard error of slope (with R example)?

Tags: r, regression

In R, you can easily get the standard error of a linear regression prediction.
I want to know how that SE is actually calculated using the standard errors of the slope and intercept.

Let's say we have the following X variables:

```
x = c(3,4,6,10,8,7)
y = c(2,5,4,9,7,9)
n = length(x)
model = lm( y ~ x )
summary(model) # this gives the coefficients and SEs
predict( model ,data.frame(x=10),se.fit=T) # this shows the SE of the prediction
```

So in this case, how did R determine the SE of 1.26 for the prediction of value x=10?
And how would I correctly calculate the 95% confidence interval? Would I use the following?

```
qt( (1-0.95)/2 , n - 2 )
```

Comment: You cannot generally obtain an answer from the limited information you describe. You also need information about how the slope and intercept are correlated (or algebraically equivalent information, such as the mean of the $x$ variable values).  Formulas abound on this site: please search it for posts about [regression formulas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+standard+error+formula+answers%3A1).

Comment: I have given all information. My question is how R actually gets the SE of 1.26 in this example. What are you missing? I looked everywhere but could not find it.

Comment: You have *not* given all the necessary information, as you can ascertain by consulting any of the formulas found with that site search.  Your question explicitly asks for that calculation [only] "using the SEs of the slope and intercept." If your question really is "how do I calculate the SE of a prediction in OLS when I have the data," then see that search for the answers.